# RxJava polling + manual refresh

Tags: java, android, rx-java, polling

I have a list a want to refresh every minute.
For example the user list here : https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture/blob/master/domain/src/main/java/com/fernandocejas/android10/sample/domain/interactor/GetUserList.java

I add a periodical refresh using repeatWhen :

```
  public Observable<List<User>> buildUseCaseObservable(Void unused) {
    return this.userRepository
        .users()
        .repeatWhen(new Function<Observable<Object>, ObservableSource<?>>() {
          @Override
          public ObservableSource<?> apply(Observable<Object> objectObservable) throws Exception {
            return objectObservable.delay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
          }
        });
  }
```

It works fine this way, calling onNext every minute.
But if I want to refresh immediately this list (because of user's action or because of a notification), I don't know how to perform that.

Should I cancel/dispose the observable and restart a new one ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code I understand that the users list is generated and emitted upon subscription.

Here are some solutions I can think of, instead of unsubscribing and resubscribing upon the event to which you want to react immediately:

1. Instead of using the `repeatWhen` operator, use the [`interval` creation operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) combined with the `flatMap` to invoke the subscription to a new Observable every minute and use the `merge` operator to add reaction to the other event in which you are interested. Something like this:

   ```
   @Test
   public void intervalObservableAndImmediateReaction() throws InterruptedException {
       Observable<String> obs = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                   .cast(Object.class)                                          
                   .mergeWith(
                             Observable.just("mockedUserClick")
                                       .delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                   .flatMap(
                            timeOrClick -> Observable.just("Generated upon subscription")
                            );

       obs.subscribe(System.out::println);
       Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000); //to see the prints before ending the test
   }
   ```

   or adjusted to your needs (but the principal is the same):

   ```
   Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
               .mergeWith(RxView.clicks(buttonView))
               .flatMap(timeOrClick -> this.userRepository.users());
   ```
2. You can use the `flatMap` operator as before, even while keeping you working current implementation and without merging to an interval - just keep your working code and in another area of the programme chain it to the [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) of your choosing:

   ```
   RxView.touches(yourViewVariable)
         .flatMatp(motionEvent -> this.userRepository.users())
         .subscribe(theObserver);
   ```

   Note that in this solution the subscription is done independently to the two observables. You'll probably be better off if you use different observers, or manage a subject or something on that line. A small test I ran showed one subscriber handled subscribing to 2 different observables with no problem (in Rxjava1 - didn't check in Rxjava2 yet), but it feels iffy to me.

Comment: Using interval and mergeWith seems to be interesting, thank you. How can I trigger manually a "refresh" (instead of using RxView) ?

Comment: You could use a Subject and just call its `onNext` from wherever you want in the programme.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't concerned with adjusting the refresh time after one of the other observables emits data you can do something like the following:

```
    // Specific example of a user manually requesting
    val request = Observable.create<String> { emitter ->
        refresh.setOnClickListener {
            emitter.onNext("Click Request")
        }
    }
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap {
                userRepository.users()
            }

    // Refresh based off of your original work, could use something like interval as well
    val interval = userRepository.users()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .repeatWhen { objectObservable ->
                objectObservable.delay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            }

    // Combine them so that both emissions are received you can even add on another source
    Observable.merge(request,interval)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                contents.text = it.toString()
            }, {
                contents.text = it.toString()
            },{
                println(contents.text)
            })
```

Then you don't have to dispose and resubscribe every time

Comment: how can you merge Observable<String> with Observable<List<User>> ?